# How can I make two words appear in the same line in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles

I had this code before:

`projectName: project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No Project' : project.get('name')`

And in the render() method I had this:

```
<div className='c-card__projects'>
  Project: {card.projectName}
</div>
```

and It looked like this in the UI

[image]

Now I changed the code to take into account the color of the project like this:

```
  projectName: <div style={{color: project.get('color')}}>
    {project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No Project' : project.get('name')}
  </div>
```

And now it looks like this:

[image]

How can I do to be display in the same line as before, instead of two lines (I just wanted to change the color)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to a span for inline styling.

```
projectName: 
<span style={{color: project.get('color')}}>
    {project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No Project' : project.get('name')}
</span>
```